# Can counter in micrometer start from a set value?

Tags: java, microservices, prometheus, micrometer

I spent some time reading `Counter` of `micrometer.io`. For my specific use case I need to always start the counter with a specific value which is available at start of application.

Since the application has multiple pods I want this inital value to be set and then can be incremented by any number of pods. The only method the `Counter` supports is increment. I thought of using `Gauge` but there are various cons since my metric is always an unbounded incremental counter with a starting set value.

Has anyone solved this use case before or can there be a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`increment`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/a6fe623aab1e664e261ff2a94daf2e794a8ff728/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Counter.java#L45) a `Counter` with any arbitrary value at startup but I don't recommend doing that:

- That will be registered and published as an increment in your data
- This will happen every time you restart your applications
- Such a `Counter` will lie to you since you will not see the amount of increments but something else

Could you please tell us about your use-case, based on what you told, I think you don't need an initial value for your counter but add some sort of an instance id to your running instances (e.g.: pod name) and aggregate these (sum them) on your metrics backend.

Comment: My use case if the count the current active rows in my database, so at startup of the pods the metric (total_active_row) needs to have an initial value and then through the course of the pods life. It keeps on updating the count if we receive such events.

I know the use case is not conventional, but we don't want to query database everytime to get the count, but just at the start of application once and then increment it based on the api-requests we get

Comment: I guess the active row count can be incremented and decremented too. So I would recommend a gauge for this (see the docs). Also, a gauge is async so if you wire it into the DB, it will only be called when metrics are reported (e.g.: every minute).

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonatan mentioned: a Gauge is what you would use in this case.  You even could create a gauge that points to an instance variable that get updated.

That way you could set the instance variable to a value on startup and update it in the background to query your database. I use this technique in places where the query is too slow, so I don't want it happening during a  metric scrape.